# How to stop httrack from copying websites?

Tags: web, httrack

Httrack can download all the files stored on the server of any website. How can I stop httrack to do so? can I achieve this by using robot.txt file ?

Comment: Robot.txt will stop well-behaved robots.  If someone wants to copy the images and html from your website, they will.

Comment: so PHP cannot be copied is it ?

Comment: Generally, code folders aren't shared.  However, if the code folder isn't marked exclusive, then the code can be copied.

Comment: How to mark a code folder exclusive?

Comment: https://www.linux.com/tutorials/how-manage-file-and-folder-permissions-linux/

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in two ways as follows:

1. ROBOTS.TXT
2. .htaccess

**1st Method:**

```
User-agent: HTTrack
Disallow: /
```

**2nd Method:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^HTTrack
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```